# Edit button hidden or not based on permissions to edit

Tags: reactjs, meteor

Iʻm pretty new to meteor still and am currently creating an app that allows users to add recipes to the website, favorite them, search, etc. They will also be allowed to edit recipes but only ones that they've created and uploaded themselves. Currently the edit button shows for every user not just the owner of the recipe. I know there is a way to hide buttons but Iʻm not really sure on how to make them hidden based on the user.

This is the code i currently have for the recipe cards

```
const RecipeCard = ({ recipe }) => (
  <Col>
    <Card className="h-100">
      <Card.Header>
        <Card.Img src={recipe.picture} />
        <Card.Title><Link to={`/recipes/${recipe._id}`}>{recipe.name}</Link></Card.Title>
        <Card.Subtitle>{recipe.time}</Card.Subtitle>
        <HeartFill />
      </Card.Header>
      <Card.Body>
        <Card.Text>
          {recipe.description}
        </Card.Text>
        <h6>Tags</h6>
        <Card.Text>
          {recipe.tags.map((tag, idx) => <Badge key={`${tag}${idx}`} bg="secondary" className="mx-1">{tag}</Badge>)}
        </Card.Text>
        <Link to={`/edit/${recipe._id}`}>Edit</Link>
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
  </Col>
);
```

with this line being what shows the button.

```
<Link to={`/edit/${recipe._id}`}>Edit</Link>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a check to see whether the recipe's author matches the current user's username (or other identifying info).

```js
{recipe.author === Meteor.user()?.username ? 
<Link to={`/edit/${recipe._id}`}>Edit</Link> : 
''}
```

This ternary statement will display the edit button if the current user's username matches the name of the author, and nothing if it doesn't. This assumes that each recipe has an `author` and that it matches with a user's `username`.